# Nullable<T> for generic method in c#?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

How can I write a generic method that can take a Nullable object to use as an extension method.  I want to add an XElement to a parent element, but only if the value to be used is not null.

e.g.

```
public static XElement AddOptionalElement<T>(this XElement parentElement, string childname, T childValue){
...
code to check if value is null
add element to parent here if not null
...
}
```

If I make this `AddOptionalElement<T?>(...)` then I get compiler errors.
If I make this `AddOptionalElement<Nullable<T>>(...)` then I get compiler errors.

Is there a way I can acheive this?

I know I can make my call to the method:

```
parent.AddOptionalElement<MyType?>(...)
```

but is this the only way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public static XElement AddOptionalElement<T>(
    this XElement parentElement, string childname, T? childValue)
    where T : struct
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>'

Comment: It still will have the compiler error as we need to indicate that T need to be non-nullable.

Comment: @BlueChippy: Was just fixing that as you commented!

Comment: Thanks LukeH: final q?  Is an Enum a struct?

Comment: @BlueChippy: Yes, enums are value-types so the `struct` constraint allows them.

Answer (score 4):

You need to constrain `T` to be a `struct` - otherwise it cannot be nullable.

```
public static XElement AddOptionalElement<T>(this XElement parentElement, 
                                             string childname, 
                                             T? childValue) where T: struct { ... }
```

Comment: Its not the "this" that needs to be nullable, but one of the other parameters.  e.g. MethodName<T>(this XElement parent, "NeedANullableHere" value)

Comment: Edited... your "take a Nullable object to use as an extension method" was a little bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

try
 `AddOptionalElement<T>(T? param) where T: struct { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

[The Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) type has the constraint `where T : struct, new()` so your method obviuosly should contain the `struct` constraint to make `Nullable<T>` working fine. The resulting method should look like:

```
public static XElement AddOptionalElement<T>(this XElement parentElement, string childname, T? childValue) where T : struct
    {
      // TODO: your implementation here
    }
```

Comment: `struct` implies `new()` as constraint, no need to add it explicitly.